# Catalyzation in Carbonic Acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, energy

I understand the basics of carbonic acid + 1 kcal breaking down into water and carbon dioxide.

However, my professor wants me to draw an energy map showing the catalyst in human blood reducing the activation energy from 21 kcal to 12 kcal. I've never run into an energy map nor have we discussed this catalyst in class yet.

Anyone have a resource I can look at?

Comment: I suspect that your professor is looking for an [energy profile.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_profile_%28chemistry%29)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_anhydrase

Comment: Removed 'super basic' from the title. It was confusing; I thought it was talking about [superbases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superbase).